# Missing aside text on first answer queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, review

The aside that shows when looking at review queues when out of votes for the First Answers queue is blank.

[image: Queues screenshot]

Comment: Possibly related: [this bug reported on the MSE post "Review queue workflows - Final release"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369040/335251)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the report - this should be fixed in prod this afternoon

**Meta Issue**: [Review queue "First questions" does not show any message when reaching the maximum number of daily votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375127/209031)